# Can someone identify and list the actors in the preview for The Fall of Five?

Tags: lorien-legacies, fall-of-five

There was [this official video preview](http://iamnumberfourfans.com/3915/the-fall-of-five-official-trailer/) of *The Fall of Five* on August 23, four days before it was released. Does this mean that they are going to produce a movie from *The Fall of Five* when they haven't done the 2nd and 3rd books in the series?

Also, are any of the actors in the trailer from the *I Am Number Four* movie? Can someone list the names of people in the video and who they correspond with?

Comment: on a related note, Dreamworks currently has no plans to produce movies for any of the subsequent books; the proposed sequel was shelved pretty quickly and never heard from again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the [Facebook page](https://www.facebook.com/EscapeGoatPictures) of the company that produced it. It lists some of the actors:

Cyrus Salvia as Number Nine

Annie Baltic as Ella

Sarah Martinez as Number Six?

Bryant Lee

Brett Temple

Brett Austin Temple

If someone could figure out which of the other names corresponds to which number and edit it in, that would be great. There's also Malcolm , which I don't think is on this list.

Answer (score 1):

This is the OFFICIAL BOOK TRAILER. Looks like a college project at that, the "talent" is all studenty. They aren't even Z-listers ;)

It is in no way related to the movie from Dreamworks. It is just to advertise the book..